# Id: cannot find name for group ID 197121

Tags: sudo, git-bash

I am running the command : sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\user57.config on windows with git bash and it gives me such error: `id: cannot find name for group ID 197121`. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `git-bash` on Windows:

```
chown -R $USERNAME:$(id -g $USERNAME) /c/Users/user57.config
```

explanation:

- `$USER` is not set, use `$USERNAME` instead
- `id -g` works, but not `id -n`, however chown will work with the group id
- target path with forward slash (rather than backslash) starting with `/c/` for the drive letter